# Migrating MySQL data and looking up new FK?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration, data-migration

I'm trying to migrate application data from one MySQL DB to another (with a different schema, of course) and I'm running into trouble when trying to maintain relationships from the old DB to the new.

### Structure

The basic idea is an event management system, where different groups/departments can create events and shifts for these events.

#### DB Structure

I'm only showing relevant columns to keep things simple(r)

```
*Old DB*
Departments (PK Dept_ID)
Events (PK Event_ID, FK Dept_ID)
Shifts (PK Shift_ID, FK Event_ID, FK Dept_ID)

*New DB*
departments (PK id)
events (PK id, FK department_id)
shifts (PK id, FK event_id)
```

Migrating Departments and Events was pretty straightforward with `INSERT...SELECT` queries. For shifts, well... this is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO newDB.shifts (event_id, start, end, notes)
    SELECT
        (SELECT C.id FROM newDB.events C INNER JOIN oldDB.events E 
        ON E.Title = C.title AND E.StartTime = C.start_time AND E.Location = C.location),
        * title, start, end combination is unique *
    Start, End, Notes FROM oldDB.shifts S
    WHERE S.Dept_ID = @oldDeptId;
```

I started at the top of the relationship chain and migrated a single department (Dept_ID is set in @oldDeptId variable), then migrated all events from this department using a similar `INSERT...SELECT` query. Now, when I copy the old shift data, I need the `newDB.shifts.event_id` value to match the updated `newDB.events.id` value which is assigned as an auto increment value to maintain the relationship.

The `INNER JOIN` subquery returns all `newDB.event.id` matched to the correct `oldDB.Event.Event_ID` as expected, however the subquery can only return one result (MySQL Error 1242).

Am I on the right track, or is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Why does your query involve columns such as `start` which do not appear in the table definition?  Can you elaborate on the logic you are trying to use to determine the `event_id` value to be inserted into the new `shifts` table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I really only included the primary/foreign keys in the structure to try to give a sense of the relationships. Each table has several other columns (title, address, start/end times, etc) that I didn't think were important. I've expanded what I'm trying to do in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner query returns a complete table, while you are only allowed to get a single value there (that is what your error message says). If `title, start, end` is really unique, you can use it in a `join` to get your new pk, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO newDB.shifts (event_id, start, end, notes)
SELECT C.id, S.Start, S.End, S.Notes 
from oldDB.shifts S
join oldDB.events E
on E.Event_ID = S.Event_ID
join newDB.events C   
on E.Title = C.title AND E.StartTime = C.start_time AND E.Location = C.location;
```

You don't need to do it per department, you can migrate the table as a whole.

If `title, start, end` is not unique (or as general purpose idea for the future), you can temporarily add the old pks to the new tables, and `join`   on these to get the new pk from the old one - because they are unique in any scenario. You can then e.g. simply use

```
INSERT INTO newDB.shifts (event_id, start, end, notes)
SELECT C.id, S.Start, S.End, S.Notes 
from oldDB.shifts S
join newDB.events C   
on C.old_event_id = S.event_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, these are a both things I hadn't thought of that I can use. I agree it would be easier to migrate the whole table instead of per department, but I'd like to only move data for departments that will be continuing to use the app. I'm sure I can make this work fine with an appropriate `WHERE` clause. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jason yes, you can simply add your `WHERE S.Dept_ID = @oldDeptId` again to do it per department. Good luck with your migration.